# Deleting an array created by new [] with delete []

Tags: c++

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;


struct my{
  int a;
  ~my(){
    cout << "d\n";
  }
};
int main(){
  my* a = new my[100];
  // cout << (void*)a << " " << (void*)&(a[0]) << endl;
  delete a; // I know I should use delete [], 
            // but just to find out what would happen if I do this.
}
```

The program is printing `d` and then gives a segmentation fault. The implementation of `delete`  assumes that an area of size `sizeof(type)` has been allocated and that much memory has to be freed. Whereas `delete []` first reads the number of elements which has been allocated. I found that most implementations store this number `n` in the beginning of the allocated memory. `delete []` fetches `n` from the beginning and the goes on to free `n * sizeof(type)` bytes of allocated memory. I don't understand why the above program gives segfault. I tried printing the addresses `a` and `&(a[0])` and they are exactly the same, so any possibility that `delete` was trying to clear the area where `n` was stored is simply not true. Can someone please tell what is going on?

Note: This does not happen when we allocate arrays of basic types like `int`, `double` etc.

Comment: It crashes because it is undefined behavior. The End.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Why is it UB? If we go by the implementation of these functions, it should be clear why it is happening.

Comment: `new` must be matched with `delete`, and `new[]` ***must*** be matched with `delete[]`. That is what the C++ language specification says. Anything else is wrong.

Comment: It is undefined behavior because arrays constructed by `new[]` must be destroyed with `delete[]`. Using `delete` is undefined behavior. The End.

Comment: Because for example you can use memory sanitizer which explicitly fails on this scenario.

Comment: And about your printing of addresses, remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. So using `a` when a pointer is expected will automatically give you `&a[0]`. So you print the exact same thing twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour on using `delete` on a pointer acquired by `new[]` is *undefined*. (Some C++ runtime libraries are implemented in such a way that an array of plain old data types is `delete`d correctly when you write `delete`).

Really there is nothing else to say.

Answer (score 1):

what was allocated with `new` must be freed by `delete`, what was by `new[]` must be freed by `delete[]`.

- don't mix `new` for allocating and another APIs to free like Windows `GlobalFree()`.

to delete correctly a:

```
delete[] a;
```

- if you call `delete` in a dynamic array will cause an `undefined behaviour`